# Is the completion of a CAT(0) open ball a closed ball?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, completion, non-positive-curvature

It is well-known that the completion of a metric space which is homeomorphic to a ball can be very wild; in fact, I think, every compact manifold is the closure of an open ball!

But CAT(0) spaces are very different from general manifolds. If I have a CAT(0) with the path metric, that is totally bounded, and that is homeomorphic to an open ball, will its completion be a closed ball?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is "totally bounded"? "homeomorphic to an open ball", what does it mean? open ball of what?

Comment: I am not able to construct an example right now with bare hands, but I would expect that the topology on the closure could be strictly finer, maybe even discrete on the boundary in certain examples.

Comment: @SebastianGoette thanks; so what's the difference with "bounded"? Also what's a CAT(0) with the path metric, since a CAT(0) space is by definition geodesic?

Comment: So for the moment I'd have the following translation in standard mathematical language: *Let a bounded CAT(0) metric space be homeomorphic to an open ball of some Euclidean space. Is its completion homeomorphic to a closed ball (in the same Euclidean space)?*

Comment: @YCor Something is totally bounded if it can be covered with finitely many balls of fixed radius r, no matter how small r is. It is a famous result that totally bounded complete spaces are compact. While I think totally bounded and bounded are the same for path metric spaces, it couldn't hurt to be as specific as possible, especially when compactness is what I'm interested in.

Comment: @Ycor And yes, I meant a Euclidean ball. I was recently reading a series of geometric topology papers which used the word 'ball' without qualification to mean a Euclidean ball, and so my brain was still in the habit of referring to them that way.

Comment: @BrianRushton then "totally bounded" the same as assuming that the completion is compact. In particular, the 1-ball (open or closed) in a $\infty$-dimensional Hilbert space is a path metric space, CAT(0), that is not "totally bounded". On the other hand if we assume that a bounded path metric space is homeomorphic to a Euclidean space, then I don't know if it's automatically totally bounded.

Comment: @YCor, it's polite not to criticize terminology before googling to see if it's standard. The first hit for "totally bounded" is the Wikipedia article giving the definition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space .

Comment: @HJRW 1) I did't criticize "totally bounded", I asked about it. 2) I sometimes criticize standard terminology (not here), especially when I think it's misleading. 3) I have nothing against "totally bounded" 4) If my only quest about the question was "totally bounded", I would probably have googled it.

Comment: For the record, the question can be restated as: *Let a bounded CAT(0) metric space be homeomorphic to an open ball of some Euclidean space. Is its completion homeomorphic to a closed ball (in the same Euclidean space)? at least assuming if necessary that the completion is compact?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is "no".

Let $\Sigma$ be the suspension over Poincaré homology sphere.
It admits a polyhedral $\mathrm{CAT}[1]$-metric.

Let $B$ be the unit ball in the Euclidean cone $\mathrm{Cone}\,\Sigma$.

Note that $B$ is a compact $\mathrm{CAT}[0]$-space;
its interior is homeomorphic to the ball in $\mathbb{E}^5$ but its boundary is homeomorphic to $\Sigma$, which is not a manifold.

Comment: A bit of background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem

Comment: Thank you. This result seems to crop up in all the strangest of places. I appreciate your work in answering this.